# I need to sync gmail contact to my app

Tags: android, synchronization

I have built app that has functionality to sync contacts from mobile's contact now i want to add gmail contact sync button that will sync contact of gmail, that we have saved in our gmail account. 
For this i added google-api-client-android package into my work space for google credential or auth permission but it throws error i.e.

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the ---class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project (resource) google-api-client-android        
-The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files   package-info.java   /google-api-client-android/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth   line 1  Java Problem
Unable to resolve target 'android-18'   google-api-client-android       Unknown Android Target Problem
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Get contacts from the user's installed contacts app:

https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

Try understanding why it would be a very bad idea if apps could freely check other apps for their data. You've got to use the Contacts Provider and the permissions associated with it.

Edit: on second thought, you can try this:

https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client

But you're still going through an API and asking the user for permission. I want to make it clear that there is no taking information from other apps.

Answer (score 1):

This error means, you don't have API level 18 installed. Open the SDK manager and install it.

Comment: i have different different functionality with different classs that support different apis show how could i replace with api 18